# Consecutive Split/Select

Tags: apache-flink

I'm new to Flink, so sorry if this question is trivial!

Problem description :
`IoT sensors --> MQTT --> Apache Nifi --> Kafka --> Flink` (only Flink is relevante here!

Sensors send heartbeat and other events. Hearbeats are in two different formats (different versions). My goal is to unify the stream.

Here's my code:

```
SplitStream<GatewayEvent<String>> splitedStream = gatewayStream
            .split(new GatewayActionPathSplitter());

// GatewayEvent contains an 'action' (mqqt topic): 'up/hearbeat' action  contains v30 and v31 heartbeats
SplitStream<GatewayEvent<String>> heartBeatStream = splitedStream
            .select("up/heartbeat")
            .split(new HeartBeatVersionSplitter());

// Map heartbeats v31 to HeartBeat objects
DataStream<GatewayEvent<HeartBeat>> hb31Stream = heartBeatStream
        .select("V31")
        .map(new HeartBeat31Mapper());

// Map heartbeats v30 to HeartBeat objects
DataStream<GatewayEvent<HeartBeat>> hb30Stream = heartBeatStream
        .select("V30")
        .map(new HeartBeat30Mapper());

DataStream<GatewayEvent<HeartBeat>> allHBStream = hb31Stream
            .union(hb30Stream);

allHBStream.print();
```

I thought that streams will have the following events ("HB30" is HeartBeatv30, "HB31" is HearBeatv31 and "O" are other events)

`gatewayStream = HB30, O, O, HB30, HB31, HB30, O`
`splitedStream = HB30, O, O, HB30, HB31, HB30, O`
`splitedStream.select("up/heartbeat") = HB30, HB30, HB31, HB30`
`heartBeatStream = HB30, HB30, HB31, HB30`
`heartBeatStream.select("V30") = HB30, HB30, HB30` // Wrong: contains also HB31
`heartBeatStream.select("V31") = HB31` // Wrong: contains also HB30s

Can someone explain me :
1- what's wrong with this code?
2- is there another solution to implement this feature? (I have already a workaround: my GatewayActionPathSplitter class includes the hearbeat version distinction).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `split` operations are not stackable as they just apply routing strategy to the output of previous operator. There is already opened [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5031) for this issue.

Another option would be to incorporate the differentiating logic into your `map` function. Somewhat like:

```
.filter(event.getType.equals("HB31") || event.getType.equals("HB30")))
.map(event =>
  event.getType match {
    case "HB31" => new HeartBeat31Mapper()
    case "HB30" => new HeartBeat30Mapper()
  })
```

Comment: Thanks Dawid, I'll wait for this issue to be resolved.In the meantime, I'll use your workaround